# Solution to "java.net.BindException: Address already in use" error?

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij, attempting to deploy a Tomcat application, but whenever I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 1098; nested exception is: 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

Now I've manually looked for the process happening at that port via:

```
lsof -i:1098
```

And I found the java process and killed it too:

```
ps aux | grep java

kill -9 20386
```

And that worked, but I have to do this EVERYTIME I open Intellij. If I want to rerun the server without exiting Intellij, I can't, because I'll get this error. Does anyone know of a permanent fix for this and not just manually killing it everytime?

Comment: It means that something's still running on that port. You could try running on a different port?

Comment: Isn't 1098 the port for RMI? Maybe IntelliJ is using it. Just take another port.

Comment: As per @ThomasUhrig -- try port 8080, and see if you still have a problem.

Comment: Port that you are using is in use. Try using some other port.

Comment: @EngineerDollery I am using port 8080, but the JMX port keeps defaulting to 1098 which is what is throwing the error. And I can't remove it, because it needs a port.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is due to `JMX` monitoring the Tomcat instance. Tomcat will be running on port 9999 so when JMX wants to start to check for the shutdown it can't bind to this port.

One way to fix this is to define your `CATALINA_OPTS` environment variable.

Setting these properties in `JAVA_OPTS` tries to start a jmx server when you start tomcat AND when you shutdown tomcat. Hence the port already in use exception. You need to set these properties for `CATALINA_OPTS` instead of `JAVA_OPTS`. This will only run when you start tomcat.

```
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8999"
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
```

What fixes it for me is in `$HOME/.bashrc` I add this export:

`export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8999"`

Credit:
https://bowerstudios.com/node/636

Answer (score 2):

[image]Click on the skull icon after stopping server to kill all associated processes. This should help in resolving the port issue.

Comment: what is the prerequisite for seeing that skull button? On my Spring Boot project there is no such thing within that toolbar

Comment: either your server is still running or you terminated and termination did not complete.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem, I didnot kill my previous running app on the same port. I just killed it using kill -9 PID and I was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found this questions many times in Tomcat.

错误: 代理抛出异常 : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 912
3; nested exception is:     java.net.BindException: Address already in use

In tomcat
[cc@Cdf bin]$ vim catalina.sh
change the 9123 to a inactive number ,for example 8998 .
and then ,
[cc@Cdf bin]$ ./start.sh;tailf ../logs/catalina.out

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on the project --> `Run As` --> `Run Configurations` ---> On left hand side select project under Spring Boot App
--> change the JMX Port and try

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem while starting the SymmetricsDS service. Here is my solution for Linux and it works later.

```
top | grep java
kill -9 javaPID
```